# Generating a CSV table with daily SPM data in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, modis, google-drive

I'm trying to generate a CSV table in Google Earth Engine to obtain daily data of Suspended Particulate Matter (SPM) concentration in different locations over a defined period. However, when I run my code, I only get [constant] in the results, and the actual data values I need are not showing up.

Here's part of my code:

```
//MODIFICADO
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: sp_col,
    description: 'Multiple_Locations_SPM',
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'SPM_multiple wide',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Here is the code updated:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/4d95b4ce6aad20a48ba82a46a4ac09a6

depuratori: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-ecoli/assets/ARPAV_coord_depuratori

polygon: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-jhonnatanrodriguezramos01/assets/agua

What am I doing wrong? Is there just specific data that can be exported?

Comment: You are trying to export as CSV the **sp_col** Image Collection. It doesn't produce tasks errors but some fields with all records with **[constant]** or **element** values. By the way, share your asset water.

Comment: I could generate a CSV table with your data. However, your dataset **agua** has more than 200,000 features (some of them with many edges and other very small) and this complicates the process. What is representing each feature in **agua**? There is one so huge corresponding to Adriatic sea with many holes.

Comment: At following picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6G3M.jpg, inside red polygons, there are water. Inside the other large polygons there are not water. However, there are a lot of sliver polygons that should be removed. GEE spend a lot of time in them without any necessity. I recommend you fix this problem before whatever analysis in GEE.

Comment: Thanks, ""agua"" represents water bodies but I did not see those sliver polygons (fixing now). Still, what I am looking for is to have the values corresponding to each pixel's "depuratori" and "fiume" points and my idea was to clip them with **agua** polygons as a mask feature due to MODIS resolution. Is it sound?

Comment: I was able to obtain the CSV file, but now the problem is that I am getting only the values for just one point, and is giving me monthly values, how could I get daily values for each point? 

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4d95b4ce6aad20a48ba82a46a4ac09a6
depuratori: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-ecoli/assets/ARPAV_coord_depuratori
polygon: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-jhonnatanrodriguezramos01/assets/agua

Comment: SPM_band was wrong calculated. You have to map over all images for producing that band, not by using the median. I spent a lot of time trying to find the error (values for groups of 2189 images are always the same). Result must be similar to this, with blue band, in relation to variation of values: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1432cb781e5ab2f7a91b599af498de11